# Effective range of Captain Enchantment on Tier 2 Boots

Tags: league-of-legends

With the new Captain Enchantment on your tier 2 boots, allies move towards you faster.

What is the effective range of this bonus for allied champions? What is the range of the bonus for minions? Is there a visual cue that indicates someone is getting the bonus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This Lol Wiki page](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Captain) says:

- The 8% movement speed effect bonus does not show any status icon on
  affected allied champions.

  To benefit from the 8% movement speed bonus, allies must:
- be within roughly 1100 range of the aura holder
- be facing him. The movement speed stat increase is still visible even if they are not moving.

Here are a couple screenshots showing the range of the Captain effect on minions and champions.  I took the screenshots right before and after the movement speed took effect.  You can see that there is no visible buff indicator either on the unit or on the HUD.

Minions before buff:
[image: Minions pre-captain buff]
Minions with buff:
[image: Minions with captain buff]
Tristana before buff:
[image: Tristana pre-captain buff]
Tristana with buff:
[image: Tristana with captain buff]

Comment: Can you test the range on minions? Also 1100 is hard to visualize, do you have a screenshot showing the range?

Comment: I'm going to try and record a video later today.

Comment: Video is not necessary, the visual on the range is good enough. Thanks!